# how can write a query that displays the 3 most populous cities in each state?

Tags: sql-server

I hope you're doing well.
as a newbie I would like to solve this, but at the end, the result is wrong.
we have 2 tables. the City, it look like below
["1"    "New York City" "8336817"   "NY",
"2" "Los Angeles"   "3979576"   "CA",
"3" "Chicago"   "2693976"   "IL",...].

and the State that looks like below.
["AK"   "Alaska"    "731545",
"AL"    "Alabama"   "4903185",
"AR"    "Arkansas"  "3017825",...].

with this query, I fetched the most 3 populated cities in California.

select top 3 st, cityname, population from City where st='CA'  ORDER BY population desc;

this query results:
["CA"   "Los Angeles"   "3979576",
"CA"    "San Diego" "1423851",
"CA"    "San Jose"  "1021795"]

then with this query, i try to fetch the most 3 states in the country.

select top 3 statename, population from State ORDER by population DESC;

the result is :
["California"   "39512223",
"Texas"     "28995881",
"Florida"   "21477737"]

now, i try to solve my question, for each of the most populated provinces; the 3 most populated cities did not show. please help me to solve this!

select top 3 st, cityname, population from City
where st in (select top 3 st from State ORDER by population DESC)
ORDER by population DESC;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `DENSE_RANK()` analytic function here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY statename ORDER BY population DESC) rnk
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE statename IN ('California', 'Texas', 'Florida')
)

SELECT statename, cityname, population
FROM cte
WHERE rnk <= 3
ORDER BY statename, rnk;
```

Comment: thank you, i replaced city with yourTable; the result is

Comment: thank you, i replaced city with yourTable; the result  doesnt look like
below: ["CA" "Los Angeles" "3979576", "CA" "San Diego" "1423851", "CA" "San Jose" "1021795","TX" "Houston[3]" "2320268",
"TX" "San Antonio" "1547253", "TX" "Dallas" "1343573", "FL" "Jacksonville[f]" "911507", "FL" "Miami" "467963", "FL" "Tampa" "399700"]

Comment: i mean, for these states ["California", "Texas", "Florida"] we need to fetch 3 most populated cities

Comment: I clicked on the green checkmark, was ok Sir?